# How to update the picture of my contact from Facebook in HTC wildfire?

Tags: contacts, htc-wildfire

How to update the picture of my contact from Facebook in HTC wildfire? I am able to update all other contacts but not able to update my contact from facebook. I am using android version 2.2

Comment: Are you trying to grab a more recent picture from Facebook, or to select a picture saved on your phone?

Comment: @Mathew Read a recent pic from facebook..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your phone go to people.(or phonebook) choose your contact card. Press menu button/edit. Press on your photo/Facebook. And it will be updated.

Comment: This doesn't work on my Gingerbread Droid X. Editing a contact and clicking the contact icon produces a menu with 3 options: "Use this photo" / "Remove icon" / "Change icon" I'm guessing it's a Gingerbread change.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question, but I just found out how to manage default contact photos in Android 4.4.2 (KitKat) and had to share.

For Linked Contacts, select the contact, but don't edit it.  Press Menu → Mark as default.  It's counter-intuitive, but this lets you set the default Name, Phone, Email, **and** Caller ID (aka. contact photo).  Click Done and profit.